# Add number as parameter to function after I get button from DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I use this row to get from DOM button:

```
var btn = parent.parent.document.getElementById('btnZoom')
```

I get from DOM this element:

```
<button type="button" id="btnZoom" onclick="parent.ExecuteCommand()" class="button_air-medium">
    <img id="zoomMode" class="miniToolbarContant" src="...">
</button>
```

After I get the element from the DOM I need to  add to ExecuteCommand function some number as parameter.

For example number 55:

```
<button type="button" id="btnZoom" onclick="parent.ExecuteCommand(55)" class="button_air-medium">
        <img id="zoomMode" class="miniToolbarContant" src="...">
</button>
```

My question is how do I add number as parameter ExecuteCommand function afetr I get button from DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do that. One would be to set the number value as a separate data attribute on the HTML tag, and then have your `parent.ExecuteCommand()` command read it from there, via `this`:

```
var btn = parent.parent.document.getElementById('btnZoom');
btn.setAttribute('data-number', 55);
```

The other would be to add the `onclick` event handler in Javascript instead of using an attribute on the HTML tag:

```
<button type="button" id="btnZoom" class="button_air-medium">

var btn = parent.parent.document.getElementById('btnZoom');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => parent.ExecuteCommand(55));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that onclick is an attribute and you can modify the value when you get the DOM element. Just like this:

```
var btn = parent.parent.document.getElementById('btnZoom');
btn.setAttribute("onclick","parent.ExecuteCommand(55)");
```